# Save Multiple Url images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write myself a little helper to download some Chromecast backgrounds as the photos are nice.  Sp far the code I have is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadFiles() {
      var backgroundsJSON = [
        {
            "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A0tXm8gjfMU/U08VDMRGtuI/AAAAAAAAvrI/IQEscTGZyJY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/IMG_0293%2Bhe.jpg",
            "author": "Ziv Horesh"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3LiF-MBl6OE/UO5TXZ724aI/AAAAAAAAE50/JWLqdeEM9QY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/Colorado%2BRiver%2BSunset.jpg",
            "author": "Romain Guy"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wkrGBuk0DoA/Us9JnUoXnTI/AAAAAAAAkTA/yDQexzLKhKY/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/DSC_0660.JPG",
            "author": "Alistair Nicol"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1xZqgaRDIec/Tg1dMJq1vBI/AAAAAAAAALc/7m0Tpv2htVc/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/071227-4144-PtLomaReef.jpg",
            "author": "Patrick Smith"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-36YdSRh6q9w/TgtZEChvrkI/AAAAAAAJA0M/zVvIUAdwQ3Q/s1920-w1920-h1080-c/976865336_a%2Bview%2Bof%2Bqueenstown.jpg",
            "author": "Trey Ratcliff"
        }
    ]

    for (i = 0; i < backgroundsJSON.length; i++) {
      var url = backgroundsJSON[i].url;
      // Get file name from url.
      var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = function() {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
            a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            delete a;
        };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Down Load ChromeCastBackgrounds" onclick="downloadFiles();" />
</body>
</html>
```

However when I click the button on the html page - the final image is downloading 4 times rather than the 4 unique images which was what I was hoping for?

Comment: This is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ynb03juq/
EDIT: Whoops, just noticed they are all the same image

Comment: If you check the network console to see the requests - you're getting all of the images. It's the download part of it that's broken. The code with the anchor tag has some issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working

```
function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
    // for non-IE
    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileName || fileURL;
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        save.dispatchEvent(evt);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }

    // for IE
    else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
        var _window = window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
        _window.document.close();
        _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
        _window.close();
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < backgroundsJSON.length; i++) {
  var url = backgroundsJSON[i].url;
  // Get file name from url.
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];

  SaveToDisk(url, filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set asynchronous true;

change

```
xhr.open('GET', url);
```

to

```
 xhr.open('GET', url, true);
```

Comment: I believe it is true by default so doesn't make any difference

Comment: actually i just tried this code after set asyn true and it worked for me.

Comment: I dont know how as I have created a fiddle here with the propety as 'true' https://jsfiddle.net/bqjLsLtj/ - it downloads the same file 4 times not the 4 unique files